# Proof check for a theorem of fixed point iteration

Tags: numerical-methods, fixed-point-iteration

Here in this theorem, I didn't get how the author is proving part $(2)$. Can someone please help me to understand that?

In the statement of the theorem L.H.S. is $|p_n-p_{n-1}|$ and the author is proving for $|p_n-p|$

Thanks[image]

[image]

Comment: This is really obvious if you draw a picture of an interval $[a,b]$ and place your point $p_0$ and then think about the possibilities for where $p$ can lie. At worst, it's in the larger interval which has length $\max(p_0-a,b-p_0)$ and thus the distance between $p_0$ and $p$ must be smaller than this interval.

Comment: @TonyS.F., I have edited the question.